# Lambda http trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I created a lambda function in AWS.
I want to trigger it by a API Gateway/http call.

after creating the http trigger i can see the following:

[image]

but when I try to use a GET/POST calls to this address I receive "internal server error".
I checked the logs and I see the following:

> The IAM role configured on the integration or API Gateway doesn't have permissions to call the integration. Check the permissions and try again.

What should I do? which permission I need?

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/permissions.html)

> When an API is integrated with an AWS service (for example, AWS
> Lambda) in the back end, **API Gateway must also have permissions to
> access integrated AWS resources (for example, invoking a Lambda
> function) on behalf of the API caller**. To grant these permissions,
> create an IAM role of the AWS service for API Gateway type. When you
> create this role in the IAM Management console, this resulting role
> contains the following IAM trust policy that declares API Gateway as a
> trusted entity permitted to assume the role:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```